# Quitar seleccion de una fila de un JTable - Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Cuando hago click a una fila se selecciona toda esa fila pero quisiera saber como hacer para que cuando haga click en otro lugar osea fuera del Jtable se quite la selección, comparto el codigo que utilizo para seleccionar la fila y una imagen.

```
tbDocTransferir.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
tbDocTransferir.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Lo que podrías hacer seria agregarle un FocusListener a tu tbDocTransferir.

```
tbDocTransferir.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
                @Override
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                    tbDocTransferir.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
                    tbDocTransferir.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
                    tbDocTransferir.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
                    tbDocTransferir.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            });
```

Esto solo hará que cuando gane el foco la tabla se pueda seleccionar, pero cuando lo pierda no, esto solo hará que cuando se seleccione otro elemento diferente de la tabla pierda el foco, si aprieta a alguna otra parte del frame que no sea un componente no perderá el foco, para esto puedes añadirle un mouseclicked a tu frame para que al hacer click en cualquier parte del frame que no sea un componente también realice la misma acción

```
this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                    tbDocTransferir.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
                    tbDocTransferir.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
                } 
 });
```

todo se pondría en el constructor del Frame

También puedes agregar el mouseClicked en el jtable.

```
tbDocTransferir.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                    tbDocTransferir.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
                    tbDocTransferir.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
                } 
 });
```

Comment: Ya implemente los metodos, le doy click a la fila y se selecciona y cuando le doy click en el frame se quita la seleccion pero cuando quiero volver a seleccionar la fila ya no se selecciona @Sergio1871

Comment: @BrunoTorres si cuando haces click en el frame y vuelves a la fila y haces click 2 veces?

Comment: Como dice los6b puedes intentar dando doble click o intenta agregando el  mouseClicked al jtable, modiffiqué el código para que agregues dicho método igualmente en el constructor

Comment: ya implemente los metodos pero al hacer click nuevamente a la fila solo se selecciona una celda y no toda

Comment: Intenta quitando en  la opcion *setCellSelectionEnabled(true)* en ambos donde sea t*rue*

Comment: cuando vuelvo a seleccionar la fila solo se selecciona toda la columna y no la fila